# What does the letter "H" on the upper side of ADANA word and mean?

Tags: general-aviation, aeronautical-charts, instrument-procedures, vor, sid-star

As you can see on the STAR chart of Adana, there is a letter "H" with a black background for the VOR sign's line. I can't find the meaning.

[image]

Comment: Elsewhere on the chart, is a holding pattern depicted for that fix?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Customers have stated "We noticed an 'H' symbol next to an airspace
> fix/navaid in the SID/STAR chart planview. Explain what this means?"
>
> The "H" symbol serves as an indicator for crews to look for a
> published holding pattern that is shown 'off flight track' in an
> inset.

[Jeppesen Web Site](https://support.jeppesen.com/article?aid=kA20z000000CiNVCA0)